# Probability $1$, $10$, $100$, $1000$ all show up on display of calculator at some point?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I just asked this question accidentally from my older brother's account, so deleting it and asking it on mine:

From the HMMT competition:
https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2003/feb/comb/solutions.pdf

> A calculator has a display, which shows a nonnegative integer $N$, and a button, which
> replaces $N$ by a random integer chosen uniformly from the set $\{0, 1, \ldots , N − 1\}$, provided that $N > 0$. Initially, the display holds the number $N = 2003$. If the button is pressed repeatedly until $N = 0$, what is the probability that the numbers $1$, $10$, $100$, and $1000$ will each show up on the display at some point?

Here's what I did. Let's first count the total number of display sequences. Note that there's a bijection between a display sequence and a subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, 2002\}$, and so the total number of display sequences is $2^{2002}$. Now, let's count the number of display sequences that pass through $1000$, $100$, $10$, and $1$. For $2003$ to $1000$ it's $2^{1002}$, for $1000$ to $100$ it's $2^{899}$, for $100$ to $10$ it's $2^{89}$, and for $10$ to $1$ it's $2^8$. Thus the desired probability is:$${{2^{1002}2^{899}2^{89}2^8}\over{2^{2002}}} = {1\over{16}}$$However, the official answer at the above link says the answer is$${1\over{1001}} \cdot {1\over{101}} \cdot {1\over{11}} \cdot {1\over2} = {1\over{2224222}}$$So what is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all the sequences are equally probable, which is where your calculation fails.  The chance you get all the numbers because you always select the highest available is $\frac 1{2002!}$.  The chance you only get $1$ because that is the first one selected is $\frac 1{2002}$